# Php Session issue?

Tags: php

I have stored an error message in session variable and it gets displayed on page when condition becomes false. Now, i want that on refreshing the page the message disappear thus , freeing up the Session Variable.

**Code :**  **To show the error message**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['er'])): //Showing Errors on Salary form  ?>
    <div class="form-errors">
        <?php foreach ($_SESSION['er'] as $mistake): ?>
                  <p> <?php echo $mistake ?> </p>
        <?php endforeach ;?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Storing the error**

```
$_SESSION['er'] = array("Salary Must be between 10000 and 80000.");
header("Location:addSalary.php");
```

Comment: So just set the errors to null after echoing. `unset($_SESSION['er']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just unset it right after you printed error. So it will be shown only once

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['er'])): //Showing Errors on Salary form  ?>
  <div class="form-errors">
    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['er'] as $mistake): ?>
      <p> <?php echo $mistake ?> </p>
        <?php endforeach ;?>
  </div>
<?php unset($_SESSION['er']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then once you have used/sent the error message you can remove it.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['er'])): ?>
    echo '<div class="form-errors">';

    foreach ($_SESSION['er'] as $mistake): 
        echo "<p>$mistake</p>";
    endforeach;

    echo '</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['er']);
endif; 
?>
```